# How to fix impossible to use appearance font size in Android Studio configuration file

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I've accidentally set my appearance font size to I believe 1412.  I am unable to see anything in Android Studio anymore.  Is there a setting in a configuration file somewhere so that I can reset this number to a normal sized font?  I cannot use Ctrl -> Alt -> A settings, I can't see anything.  So any user interface necessary answers won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `options\ui.lnf.xml` file when IDE is not running from the [config directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519).

You can also edit the `FONT_SIZE` option inside:

```
<option name="FONT_SIZE" value="11" />
```